# Writing and Reading an ArrayList<model>

Tags: java, arraylist

So I am pretty much new at this but I have built a library project that has an ArrayList BookList which in return has elements such as String Title, String Author, and int Quantity. I have an add method and a display method and  I want to create a method that I am able to save and load the BookList when I I give the appropriate input to do so. Moreover I want to do so, so when I load the BookList I can make changes to the elements in the ArrayList and it's not just reading from the file.

```
public class Library implements Serializable{...}
```

Inside this class are my methods of saving and loading which are called in the main as well as the constructors for the ArrayList.

Save

```
   public void save(){
       try{
           FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("BookList.tmp");
           ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
           objOut.writeObject(BookList);
           objOut.close();
       }catch(Exception ev){}    
   }//end of save()
```

Load

```
    public void load(){
        try{
            FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream("BookList.tmp");
            ObjectInputStream objInput = new ObjectInputStream(fileInput);
            List<Book> BookList = (List<Book>) objInput.readObject();
            objInput.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ev){}
    }//end of load()
```

Display

```
    public void displayBooks(){
        String t; 
        String a; 
        int q;
        String s;
        Book bo = new Book();
        for(int i = 0; i<BookList.size(); i++){
            bo = BookList.get(i);
            t = bo.gettitle();
            a = bo.getauthor();
            q = bo.getquantity();
            System.out.println(i + "." + t + " " + a + " " + q);
        }//end of loop
    }//end of displayBooks()
```

But so far through the display method I have I am not able to see the BookList so I don't know if the save method works in the first place as well. So I want to know if the problem lies here or somewhere else.

Comment: `But so far through the display method I have I am not able to see the BookList` post your display method code.

Comment: Add the display method.

Comment: @Yousaf I just edited it in

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @Ravik No I don't when I load and use the display method it does not display anything.

Comment: Can you show the sequence of execution how are you adding the books to the list and then calling save/load/display?

Comment: Have you checked the contents of 'BookList.tmp' in your filesystem?

Comment: @Ravik should I post the main which has the input from the users and how it calls the methods?

Comment: forget about save and load.  Write a little program which construct the book list with 1 book, and call your `displayBooks()`.  See if it works.  It helps to eliminate where the problem is.  Simply by looking at the code, though not written smartly, shouldn't cause problem.

Comment: @khroskooper Yeah it's unreadable though.

Comment: make sure that the `BookList` in `load` method and the one in `display` method are same.

Comment: Ah, OK. If it has content then it must be saving something though. By the way, you should probably camelCase your BookList variable as it looks like a class rather than an instance.

Comment: @Yousaf I think you are right because in the load() the BookList isn't in bold which in the save() it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probable cause of your problem is that `BookList` in `display()` method and the one in `load()` method are different.

In `display` method, you are referring to `BookList` that is an instance variable but in `load` method, you have stored the result of `objInput.readObject()` method in a local variable with the same name `BookList`. I think you wanted to store the result in `BookList` that is an instance variable.

Try changing

```
List<Book> BookList = (List<Book>) objInput.readObject();
```

to

```
BookList = (List<Book>) objInput.readObject();
```

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry for wasting your time with this.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your load(), you read the book list from the ObjectInputStream, but you simply assigned to a local variable.  I believe (though poorly named) your `BookList` is an instance variable.

So your `load()` should look like

```
public void load(){
    try{
        ObjectInputStream objInput = new ObjectInputStream(FileInputStream("BookList.tmp"));
        this.books = (List<Book>) objInput.readObject();
        objInput.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ignored){
        // please add some handling please!
    }
}
```